# msp430/bin/ld: cannot find -lc

Tags: compiling, gcc, symbolic-link, dynamic-linking

I installed successfully msp430-gcc 4.7.0 compiler. The compiler at the
final stage of the linking process it shows me the following error for
Ubuntu 12.04.

```
msp430-gcc -mmcu=msp430f1611 -Wl,-Map=contiki-sky.map
-Wl,--gc-sections,--undefined=_reset_vector__,--undefined=InterruptVectors,--undefined=_copy_data_init__,--undefined=_clear_bss_init__,--undefined=_end_of_init__
hello-world.co obj_sky/contiki-sky-main.o contiki-sky.a  -o hello-world.sky
/opt/mspgccx/lib/gcc/msp430/4.7.0/../../../../msp430/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [hello-world.sky] Error 1
```

I extended my search path as msp430-gcc 4.7  was installed under `/opt` at
`~/.bashrc` to include the `/opt` directories.

```
msp430-gcc --version

msp430-gcc (GCC) 4.7.0 20120322 (mspgcc dev 20120911)
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
mswarranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
PURPOSE.

msp430-ld -version

GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.22 (mspgcc dev 20120911)
Copyright 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or (at your option) a later
version.
This program has absolutely no warranty.

$ gcc -v

Using built-in specs.
could not find specs file msp430mcu.spec
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
Target: msp430
Configured with: ../gcc-4.7.0/configure --target=msp430
--enable-languages=c --program-prefix=msp430- --prefix=/opt/mspgccx
Thread model: single
gcc version 4.7.0 20120322 (mspgcc dev 20120911) (GCC)

$ld -v

GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.22

uname -a
Linux px 3.5.0-32-generic #53~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 29 20:35:31 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install libcv-dev libcvaux-dev libhighgui-dev
sudo apt-get install glibc-static
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libc6-dev
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I solved the problem using symbolic link

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. And used a contiki script to make a clean mspgcc install on ubuntu 1204LTS. But First, installed these packages

```
sudo apt-get install  ncurses-dev flex libgmp3-dev libmpfr-dev bison  libmpc-dev texinfo zlib1g-dev automake build-essential patch
```

Then I executed a modified script from [contiki](http://wiki.contiki-os.org/doku.php?id=msp430x) (listed below).
 Don't forget to add /usr/local/bin to the PATH

```
 INSTALL_PREFIX="/usr/local/msp430"
echo The installatoin prefix:$INSTALL_PREFIX
# Switch to the tmp directory
mkdir tmp
cd tmp

# Getting
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/mspgcc/files/mspgcc/DEVEL-4.7.x/mspgcc-20120911.tar.bz2
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/mspgcc/files/msp430mcu/msp430mcu-20130321.tar.bz2
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/mspgcc/files/msp430-libc/msp430-libc-20120716.tar.bz2
wget http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/binutils/binutils-2.22.tar.bz2
wget http://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/gnu/gcc/gcc-4.7.0/gcc-4.7.0.tar.bz2

# Unpacking the tars 
tar xvfj binutils-2.22.tar.bz2
tar xvfj gcc-4.7.0.tar.bz2
tar xvfj mspgcc-20120911.tar.bz2
tar xvfj msp430mcu-20130321.tar.bz2
tar xvfj msp430-libc-20120716.tar.bz2

# 1) Incorporating the changes contained in the patch delievered in mspgcc-20120911
cd binutils-2.22
patch -p1<../mspgcc-20120911/msp430-binutils-2.22-20120911.patch
cd ..

# 2) Incorporating the changes contained in the patch delievered in mspgcc-20120911
cd gcc-4.7.0
patch -p1<../mspgcc-20120911/msp430-gcc-4.7.0-20120911.patch
cd ..

# 3) Creating new directories
mkdir binutils-2.22-msp430
mkdir gcc-4.7.0-msp430

# 4) installing binutils in INSTALL_PREFIX
cd binutils-2.22-msp430/
../binutils-2.22/configure --target=msp430 --program-prefix="msp430-" --prefix=$INSTALL_PREFIX
make
make install

# 5) Download the prerequisites
cd ../gcc-4.7.0
./contrib/download_prerequisites

# 6) compiling gcc-4.7.0 in INSTALL_PREFIX
cd ../gcc-4.7.0-msp430
../gcc-4.7.0/configure --target=msp430 --enable-languages=c --program-prefix="msp430-" --prefix=$INSTALL_PREFIX
make
make install

# 7) compiping msp430mcu in INSTALL_PREFIX
cd ../msp430mcu-20130321
MSP430MCU_ROOT=`pwd` ./scripts/install.sh ${INSTALL_PREFIX}/

# 8) compiling the msp430 lib in INSTALL_PREFIX
cd ../msp430-libc-20120716
cd src
PATH=${INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin:$PATH
make
make PREFIX=$INSTALL_PREFIX install

# cleanup
# no need since every thing created in tmp
echo Reminder: remove tmp
```