# cooja compiling error: msp430/bin/ld: cannot find -lc

Tags: compiling, gcc

I updated msp430-gcc to 4.7.0 version in InstantContiki2.6.

When I simulate the hello-world example, it shows the following error:

```
> make hello-world.sky TARGET=sky 
msp430-gcc -DCONTIKI=1 -DCONTIKI_TARGET_SKY=1 -Os -fno-strict-aliasing -ffunction-sections -Wall -mmcu=msp430f1611 -g   -I. -I../../platform/sky/. -I../../platform/sky/dev -I../../platform/sky/apps -I../../platform/sky/net -I../../cpu/msp430/f1xxx -I../../cpu/msp430/. -I../../cpu/msp430/dev -I../../core/dev -I../../core/lib -I../../core/net -I../../core/net/mac -I../../core/net/rime -I../../core/net/rpl -I../../core/sys -I../../core/cfs -I../../core/ctk -I../../core/lib/ctk -I../../core/loader -I../../core/. -I../../platform/sky/ -DAUTOSTART_ENABLE -c hello-world.c -o hello-world.co
msp430-gcc -DCONTIKI=1 -DCONTIKI_TARGET_SKY=1 -Os -fno-strict-aliasing -ffunction-sections -Wall -mmcu=msp430f1611 -g   -I. -I../../platform/sky/. -I../../platform/sky/dev -I../../platform/sky/apps -I../../platform/sky/net -I../../cpu/msp430/f1xxx -I../../cpu/msp430/. -I../../cpu/msp430/dev -I../../core/dev -I../../core/lib -I../../core/net -I../../core/net/mac -I../../core/net/rime -I../../core/net/rpl -I../../core/sys -I../../core/cfs -I../../core/ctk -I../../core/lib/ctk -I../../core/loader -I../../core/. -I../../platform/sky/ -MMD -c ../../platform/sky/./contiki-sky-main.c -o obj_sky/contiki-sky-main.o
msp430-gcc -mmcu=msp430f1611 -Wl,-Map=contiki-sky.map -Wl,--gc-sections,--undefined=_reset_vector__,--undefined=InterruptVectors,--undefined=_copy_data_init__,--undefined=_clear_bss_init__,--undefined=_end_of_init__  hello-world.co obj_sky/contiki-sky-main.o contiki-sky.a  -o hello-world.sky
/usr/local/msp430/lib/gcc/msp430/4.7.0/../../../../msp430/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
rm obj_sky/contiki-sky-main.o hello-world.co
make: *** [hello-world.sky] Error 1
Process returned error code 2
```

I read the post from: [msp430/bin/ld: cannot find -lc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/304985/msp430-bin-ld-cannot-find-lc).

But Sarwarul doesn't detail the answer.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you chose the mote type as sky mote this might happen. Try to open this same file as cooja mote and compile, it still might work...

Comment: How do I change from sky mote to cooja mote?